# Datagridview c# with SQL for Professional Developer

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

First of all I will give short description about my App:

1. C# application uses sql server to share "Tasks" between team
2. All user see the tasks
3. The event happens when user check the checkbox
4. I use a timer to refresh the grid every 4 seconds

Timer code:

```
private static int second = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            second++;
            List<Tasks> list=taskController.taskController.GetList();
            _FillGridFromList(list);
            _RefreshGrid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}

/*reFill the grid*/
private void _RefreshGrid()
{
        try
        {
            List<Tasks> list = taskController.taskController.GetList();
            _FillGridFromList(list);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Unable to Retrive Data from Server", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}

/*This function will fill userGridView from Arraylist that get from SQL */
private void _FillGridFromList(List<Tasks> list)
{
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

        try
        {
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable("sheet");
            System.Data.DataSet tmpSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            DataRow row = table1.NewRow();

            table1.Columns.Add("ID");
            table1.Columns.Add("Title");
            table1.Columns.Add("Description");
            table1.Columns.Add("Preiority");
            table1.Columns.Add("Status");
            table1.Columns.Add("Done By");
            table1.Columns.Add("Start Date");


            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                Tasks tmp = (Tasks)list[i];
                row[j++] = tmp.ID;
                row[j++] = tmp.Name;
                row[j++] = tmp.Description;
                row[j++] = tmp.Preiority;
                row[j++] = tmp.Status;
                row[j++] = tmp.Done_By;
                row[j++] = tmp.Start_Date;


                j = 0;
                table1.Rows.Add(row);
                row = table1.NewRow();
            }

            tmpSet.Tables.Add(table1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tmpSet.Tables[0];
           // dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].ReadOnly = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i].Done_By.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;

                    if (list[i].Done_By != utility.Util.User.Display_Name)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].ReadOnly = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = false;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if(second > 5)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell drx = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dr.Cells[0];
                    if(sender == drx)

                    if (drx.Selected != null) //Cells[0] Because in cell 0th cell we have added checkbox
                    {
                        if (drx.Selected==true && dr.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == utility.Util.User.Display_Name)
                        {
                            Tasks tsk = taskController.taskController.Read(dr.Cells[1].Value + "");
                            {
                                tsk.Done_By = "";
                                tsk.Status = "";
                                taskController.taskController.Update(tsk);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (drx.Selected !=true)
                            {
                                Tasks tsk = taskController.taskController.Read(dr.Cells[1].Value + "");

                                    tsk.Done_By = utility.Util.User.Display_Name;
                                    tsk.Status = "Closed";
                                    taskController.taskController.Update(tsk);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

The main problem is that when I fill the form again the listener is called because I rebuild the gridview.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Rdv.png

Comment: I understood the application but not exactly understood the problem you are facing. what that "the listener called" means? Could you please help me to understand that.

Comment: Apart from the main question, your timer tick event does exactly the same as `_RefreshGrid`, but then you call `_RefreshGrid` also. The code could be entirely replaced with just a `_RefreshGrid`. I would recommend after this question is answered, that you head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and post the code there for more info on optimizing it

Comment: The problem happened when this function call
   private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

this function called every time when I fill grid view 
I need it to run only when mouse clicked on checkbox

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using the below code :

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex+"   "+e.ColumnIndex);

     //   Int32 selectedRowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
       // Int32 selectedColumnCount = dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

        if ( e.ColumnIndex == 0  && e.RowIndex >= 0  )
        {
            string x=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[0].Value == false && x!=null )
            {
                if(x==Util.User.Display_Name)
                {
                    Tasks tsk = taskController.taskController.Read(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[1].Value + "");
                    tsk.Done_By = "";
                    tsk.Status = "";
                    taskController.taskController.Update(tsk);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[0].Value == true)
                {
                    Tasks tsk = taskController.taskController.Read(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].Cells[1].Value + "");

                    tsk.Done_By = utility.Util.User.Display_Name;
                    tsk.Status = "Closed";
                    taskController.taskController.Update(tsk);
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

I only change the type of listener from private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_1
to
  private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick